# Best way to store database file on a NAS and run the server on a computer

Tags: networking, mysql, database, network-attached-storage, nosql

I have a txt file more than 250go
I want to create a database with that and access it by a python program that I'll  be coding.

I have a NAS server on my local network ( 1gbit network )
And I would want to :
Store the database on the NAS
Run the server on my computer

Run my python program on a distant computer, this program will ask my computer ( that is run as the server ) data that are stored on my NAS

So questions :
its possible ?
its worse ?
And what is the best technology to do that ? SQL ? NoSql ? ect.

I'm a beginner on computing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

- NAS is fine for a database.  There could be some surprises in performance, etc.
- NAS is mostly indistinguishable from the disk on your computer.
- Depending on a lot of details that you have not provided, the 260GB of data may expand to 800GB when it is put into the database.  That is, it might all fit in 1TB.  Or it might not.
- (I do not know what it takes to configure the NAS; quite possibly that is "automatic" and will simply show up when you use "file manager" or "mount".  You have not even mentioned what OS you are using.)
- 250GB *may* take days to copy into the database.  If at all possible, use a tool, not simplistic python code.  (I have answered questions about people who have a python loop: read a line, INSERT into database, loop.  That's *not* efficient.)